# Sub-domain tangle (knotsmith required)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, subdomain, directory-structure

I seem to have painted myself into a corner with my plans for a series of website sub-domains. I wonder if my plans can be rescued or have I truly shot myself in the foot and would need to totally re-write a ton of stuff? Here's the problem:

I planned a series of sub-domain sites all dealing with variations on a theme. For illustrative purposes let's pretend I have the site www.colour.com (this is the 'hub' whose files reside in public_html) and then I add subdomains red.colour.com (in public_html/red), green.colour.com (in public_html/green) and blue.colour.com (in public_html/blue). Ok all good up to this point.

The thing is that these sites all share a lot of resources in common - style sheets, Javascripts, images etc. These are resources I don't want to replicate because it's a waste of space, but more importantly I don't want to risk developing different versions of files and them not all keeping in step with each other. So I did what I thought was the sane thing and I store all these at the 'hub' (in public_html/css, public_html/js etc).

What I discovered when my site went nearly live was that as soon as I defined e.g. public_html/red as red.colour.com, it could no longer 'see' any of it's supporting files that were located one level higher (in ../) and so the appearence and functionality broke down into a complete screen mess.

Short of a major re-write, is there any way out of this mess that anyone can think of?

Thanks in advance!

Frank.

Comment: Frank, we need more info.  How are you implementing your subdomains: with separate vhosts, or by `%{HTTP_HOST}` decoding?  What you ask is easily doable but depends on which.  Also if you are on a shared hosting plan, do a `phpinfo()` and let us know if your provider has set up any Environment or Server variables with the same value as your **DOCUMENT_ROOT**.  And then I can post a solution. Thanks

Comment: Hi Terry. So sorry I only just saw your comments here. You might have saved me hours of hard work and stress! I did solve the issue and just posted my own answer here. It seems succinct enough, but if you can see a weakness in it and have a better solution I'd like to hear of it! Trying to answer your questions is tough. I set the sub domains through cpanel. How that is implemented I don't know - I am out of my depth. The 2nd question you asked: PHPRC, _SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"], _SERVER["PHPRC"], _ENV["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] all have the same value as DOCUMENT_ROOT. Hope that helps! Frank.

Comment: Frank, I note below that you are on a shared service, so I've added an htaccess tag. Also check your inbox.  When some posts a comment to you, it is linked there :)

Comment: I've voted the Q because your answer shows that you've tried to research and solve this yourself -- but I don't think the answer is the best hence the bump on the Q and not the A  :-)

Comment: Thanks TerryE. Not the best? Can you suggest how I might improve on it please? Thank you.

Comment: That's what my answer is about ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I cracked it!
It required 1 pint of blood, 2 gallons of sweat and 3 magnums of tears, but I finally cracked it.
The secret is to use mod.rewrite as I was starting to suspect. You can indeed not address areas above the root, but there are other ways of refering to such locations, specifically you can refer to files or directories that 'don't exist' using the ReWrite conditions here:

```
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
```

So for example, when you want to refer to the style sheet directory that was at a higher level than the currect context, you would refer to ../css, but after you've made the current context into it's own sub-domain, ../css no longer exists. That means you can make a match with one or both of the above rewrite conditions. Now it's just a case of pointng the client to the (e.g.) css directory via the original domain, www.colour.com/css, in my example. Here, for completeness, and to help any other poor soul from killing themselves over this (I had to learn regular expressions, mod.rewrite and Lord knows what else in 6 hours to solve this one! so I hope someone else benefits as well as me!)

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.colours.com/$1   [R=301,L]
```

There may be some other directives worth adding such as to make it not rewrite hidden files, to prevent it looping etc but I haven't learn enough about mod.rewrite yet to make this squeeky clean. However it does work as it is and that is 99.99999% of my main goal.

*Edit one week on.*

Having lived with this solution a while I have to admit that there is a price to pay for this little bit of magic. I'm no expert as you will have gleaned, but it seems to me that this solution leads the browser to request each of the resources involved twice. This might not be a problem if your site is small and the efficiency hit unnoticeable, but if you want to be a stickler for optimum load times, then you might have to weigh up the pro's and con's of using this solution versus recoding your links into something more direct. Just so you know!

Comment: I'm impressed that this works.  The really strange thing is that it translates a request to `http://foo.com/../css/` to `http://bar.com/css/`.  Notice that the `../` has been dropped implicitly.  Do you know if this feature is documented?

Comment: @cooling, no it doesn't.  This is a **shared** service so **www** maps to **DOCROOT**, **red** to **DOCROOT/red** etc. so redirecting `http://red.colours.com/css/style.css` to `http://www.colours.com/css/style.css` just removes the `red/` in the **REQUEST_FILENAME**.

Comment: @TerryE See the OPs first comment to my answer *(I've un-deleted it so that you can read it).* He's got a file in `red.colour.com/` with a style sheet reference to `../css/foo.css`.  His solution magically changes a request for this file to a redirect to `www.colour.com/css/foo.css` dropping the `../`.  I've tested this in telnet and it's doing just that.  Feel free to test it yourself and post your findings.

Comment: My first thought was to use symlinks, which should be fine on shared Linux hosting. But glad you fixed it!

Answer (score -2):

Frank, one slight tease: give us XYZ "then I can post a solution" isn't quite consistent with "every source including my web hosting company said it wasn't possible to do this".

Your approach is only sort doing what you want because a 301 redirect like this just passes the problem back to the client's browser telling it to refetch the resource from your other subdomain so it does two request for each resource -- which slows down the load time at the client.

Your first solution is that you could have done by just directly coding `http://common.colour.com/...` in your **src** and **href** attributes in your HTML.  But this has the downside that you need to change your scripts.  This approach is actually quite common as many high volume sites use a separate domain for such static resource and now often use a [CDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_delivery_network) for this. It can also have performance advantages as browsers will typically open two streams per domain for loading content but parallel up requests to separate streams.

Your second solution is to do this within your servers filesystem.  What you need to do is to create symbolic links for DOCROOT/red/css to DOCROOT/css etc.  If you are scripting in PHP you can do this by creating and executing a temporary configuration script in your DOCROOT and invoke it to add these links (which appear in your FTP browser as separate directory copies but in fact all point to shared resources.  The key function that you need use is [symlink()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.symlink.php) like this:

```php
<?php
$root=dirname(__FILE__);
foreach( array( 'red', 'green', 'blue') as $c ){
  foreach( array( 'css', 'js' ) as $d ) {
    symlink( "$root/$c", "$root/$d/$c);
  }
}
```

You'd need to tweak the colours and resource directories.  Note that I've just typed this in and not debugged it -- costs extra ;-)

The third solution is to use an `.htaccess` file, but to do internal redirects rather than external ones.  Here the Apache rewrite module maps the request directly to a different path/filename.  I assume that your cpanel allows you to map **XXX.colour.com** to **DOCROOT/xxx** etc. so that a "`GET /css/sheet.css`" to a **HTTP_HOST** `red.colour.com` gets processed as `DOCROOT/red/css/sheet.css`.  How you approach this depends on whether you use a single `.htaccess` at DOCROOT or separate `red/.htaccess` etc.  If the former you can use a rule like:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase   /

RewriteRule (red|green|blue)/(css|js|images)/(.*)  /$2/$3 [L]
```

You do want the leading / on the rule target string here.

Try these out, and hope this helps :-)

Comment: @couling: what are you blathering about? (a) The only person who discussed or infered "not re-coding" is _you_. (b) My second option is to add some symlinks; showing how to do this with a one-time config script is ***not*** recoding the app.  (c) My third option is to add some lines to an `.htaccess` file rather than a `vconf` file as in your case. Again ***not*** recoding.  At least the OP can do this.  If you are going to downvote an answer, do it for rational reasons.

Comment: Sorry, that response was a little too strong.  The OP mentioned nothing about recoding, but I agree that it did come up in your answer discussion.  However when 2 out of 3 options don't involve recoding the app, I still understand the rationale for your remarks.  This is supposed to be a vehicle for helping posters, not a competition between respondents :-)

Comment: Re the 400 status on a request embedding `/../` -- yes, but since I don't suggest using `/../` why is that at all relevant to my options?  I actually avoided that bear trap.  I am not changing your suggested approach just suggestion 3 alternatives of my own.

Comment: OK so my option 1 doesn't work for his clarification.  But just because the OP refers to `/..`  this is just a shorthand that _any_ \*nix user users to mean "the parent directory".  I understand that, so do you no doubt. That doesn't mean that he's build this into URIs or even needs to.  The OP is on a shared server.  What I describe is the bog standard approach for doing this on a shared server.  S\*\*t, I do it myself for my personal public services, e.g. [my blog](http://blog.ellisons.org.uk/).

Comment: Well you wouldn't expect Frank to know how to make an Alias because he's using a shared hosting solution and you don't / can't use Alias here.  I also read the references to "../css" as subjunctive (what-if discussion) not actual hard coded.  Let's just focus on how we can solve Frank's issues on his **shared hosting** service, eh?

Comment: Couling, my main point was that issuing external 301 redirects is a functional solution, but this is still going to involve twice as many browser requests which will slow end-user response still remains.  I agree that it's up to Frank to decide whether this is an issue for him.  This discussion hasn't help him and we're both to blame here :-(

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/7631/discussion-between-couling-and-terrye)